# Apply same Margin-Left value from one class to another

Tags: jquery, css

I have two div's, classes `parallax-slider` and `parallax-bg`.

`parallax-bg` has a `margin-left` class associated with it that changes depending on window resize or browser size.

I'm looking to apply replicate this to `parallax-slider` and make it so that it has the same `margin-left` css element as `parallax-bg`

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".parallax-slider").css({
       'margin-left': ($(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft").replace('px', ''))
    });
  $(window).resize(function(){
 $(".parallax-slider").css({
      'margin-left': ($(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft").replace('px', ''))
   });
 });
});
```

But this is not working, and only adding a `margin-left: 0px;` attribute to `parallax-slider`

What am I doing wrong so that I may get the margin-left attribute of `parallax-bg` to apply it to `parallax-slider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing replace('px', '') and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parallax-slider").css({
    'margin-left': $(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".parallax-slider").css({
      'margin-left': $(".parallax-bg").css("marginLeft")
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x0aderjj/1/

Comment: Thank you.  Because `parallax-bg` was being generated after page load I needed to encapsulate this into a `$(document).ready(function()` rather than a `$(window).load(function()`.. added a time delay and a fade-in and is working great :)